# Paypal sandbox mode payment not completing?

Tags: laravel, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal PG in my project but due to some issue I am not able to complete the payment as I am not able to use any of the dummy cards to succeed the payment
I have tried so many cards but no success at all
[image: paypal error]
every time this erros comes not matter which card I am using so any idea why this is happening and what may be the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What cards are you attempting to use? The sandbox will only accept random cards from [the dashboard credit card generator](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdashboard%2FcreditCardGenerator&intent=developer&ctxId=ulb77e28f85e2b4ef6a46ec42b8fd11f62)

Comment: yes sir I have used the same some more random dummy cards

Comment: What country is the receiver account? India payment capabilities are limited. In any case, you shouldn't need to add a card -- just use accounts created in https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdashboard%2Faccounts which already come with cards in their wallets

Comment: US account but I have tried all types of cards but no success ....

Comment: Use a non-Indian payer

Comment: yes sir also tried other cards

Comment: It says country/region India in your screenshot. But anyway as mentioned earlier the best solution is to use an account that already has a card.